# webpack4 does not compile all html files?

Tags: html, webpack

> I initially did not correctly understand the essence of the problem, I correct the question, so as to more accurately formulate the problem ...

There is such an assembly ***`webpack`***:

```js
'use strict';
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require("uglifyjs-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require("optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');


const minimizerBlock = {
  minimizer: [
    new UglifyJsPlugin({
      uglifyOptions: {
        warnings: false,
        parse: {},
        compress: {},
        mangle: true,
        output: null,
        toplevel: false,
        nameCache: null,
        ie8: false,
        keep_fnames: false,
      },
    }),
    new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({})
  ]
}

const config = {
  entry: {
    main: './frontend/src/index.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './public'),
    filename: 'main.js'
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    port: 8888,
    overlay: true,
    proxy: {
      '/api': 'http://localhost:8889'
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader", "less-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.sass$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
      },
      //{ test: /\.(ttf|eot|woff|woff2|png|jpg|jpeg|svg|gif|webp)$/, loader: 'url-loader', },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|svg|gif|webp)$/,
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, './frontend/binary/image/')
        ],
        use: [{
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            name: 'image/[name].[ext]',
          }
        }]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, './frontend/binary/fonts/')
        ],
        use: [{
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            name: 'fonts/[name].[ext]',
          }
        }]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(mp3)$/,
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, './frontend/binary/audio/')
        ],
        use: [{
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            name: 'audio/[name].[ext]',
          }
        }]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(html)$/,
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, './frontend/pages/')
        ],
        use: [{
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            name: '[path][name].[ext]',
          }
        }]
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: './index.css',
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend/src/', 'template.html'),
      filename: 'index.html',
      favicon: 'frontend/binary/image/icons/iconfinder_tech_0001_4023871.png',

    }),

  ]
};
module.exports = (env, options) => {
  let production = options.mode == 'production';
  config.devtool = production ? false : 'inline-cheap-module-source-map';
  config.optimization = production ? minimizerBlock : {};
  return config;
}
```

[image]

There is a `src folder - template.html file, in which there is such a part of the layout

```
 <div id="root">
   <img src="${require(`../binary/image/icons/iconfinder_tech_0001_4023871.png`)}" alt="" />
</div>
```

which after compilation  `webpack`

reincarnated in `index.html in the public` folder, I get this result

```
<div id="root">
  <img src="images/iconfinder_tech_0001_4023871.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

And it works.

At the same time `src` there is a folder`pages` with different pages, in which there is the same piece of typesetting

```
<header>
   <img src="${require(`../../../../binary/image/sheelak/0viber-image.jpg`)}" alt=""/>
</header>
```

and after running `webpack` a folder with these files is created and here is the result

```
 <header>
   <img src="${require(`../../../../binary/image/sheelak/0viber-image.jpg`)}" alt=""/>
</header>
```

[image]

And then the problem of `require` for`img` which in `header` does not work

getting an error.

[image]

Tell me what's wrong with my webpack?

[Link to the project](https://github.com/sarnor/club)

Comment: Still experiencing the issue?

Comment: Abestrad, yes, I have not solved this problem yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shall use `html-loader` with `interpolate` flag enabled:

```
       {
            test: /\.(html)$/,
            include: [
                path.resolve(__dirname, './frontend/pages/')
            ],
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'file-loader'
                },
                {
                    loader: 'extract-loader'
                },
                {
                    loader: 'html-loader',
                    options: {
                        interpolate: true,
                    }
                }
            ],
            exclude: [
                path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend/src/', 'template.html')
            ]
        }
```

I have create pr to fix your problem: https://github.com/sarnor/club/pull/1.

Also noting that interpolation is ugly when you can just write image source like: `<img src="../../image/icons/iconfinder_tech_0001_4023871.png"`.

Also noting that your relative url was pointing to wrong directory, you were missing `../` in your url.

Comment: @Air I'm glad I could help. warmatebebi ^_^

Comment: Shenc gisurveb warmatebebs...)

Comment: [Hi, you can look at the question ... Maybe how can you help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67999709/build-angular-12-without-angular-cli-on-webpack-5)

Answer (score 0):

You're using `file-loader` on your html files, which I don't believe attempts to parse anything inside the file, it simply copies it into the output folder.

I'd suggest trying to use `html-loader` instead, and see if that fixes the issue.

In particular, you need to change this section:

```
{
  test: /\.(html)$/,
  include: [
    path.resolve(__dirname, './frontend/pages/')
  ],
  use: [{
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
      name: '[path][name].[ext]',
    }
  }]
}
```

to look like this:

```
{
  test: /\.(html)$/,
  include: [
    path.resolve(__dirname, './frontend/pages/')
  ],
  use: [{
    loader: 'html-loader',
    options: {
      name: '[path][name].[ext]',
    }
  }]
}
```

And possibly install the html-loader using:

```
npm i -D html-loader
```

Comment: I already did it...
Next, I have a script called "JS" that imports these "HTML" files, but if I add "html-loader" import does not occur

Comment: I can't catch the point. I want to understand, I do not ask for a ready-made example. I love to understand what I am doing. Should I use and `html-loader` at `file-loader`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know when to which loader read:

https://webpack.js.org/loaders/
 and

[(Webpack) Using the url-loader or file-loader, do I really have to include a require() in my .js for every static image I want to include?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37796200/webpack-using-the-url-loader-or-file-loader-do-i-really-have-to-include-a-req)

here for images I think `url-loader` is good since it can also render base-64 encode image links as images.

Try :

```
            {
                test: /\.(jpg|png|gif|eot|woff2|woff|ttf|ico|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                loader: ["url-loader?limit=100&name=static/[name]_[hash].[ext]"]
            }
```

What it will do? this will take any file of type `jpg|png|gif|eot|woff2|woff|ttf|ico|svg` & emit to folder `static`(can be any name also optional) & add hash to names. It will not only emit image & fonts but also limit size of any file to 100 kb & also add unique hash each time to name of static resources making sure any change in image with same name will also refresh cache.

Comment: url-loader, has nothing to do with this issue

Answer (score 0):

can you remove below line from config and check

```
favicon: 'frontend/binary/image/icons/iconfinder_tech_0001_4023871.png'
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a problem of loader but the way you are using `template literals`. Backticks need to wrap `${}`

```
<div id="root">
   <img src=`${require("../binary/image/icons/iconfinder_tech_0001_4023871.png")}` alt="" />
</div>
```

Similarly you would have

```
<header>
   <img src=`${require("../../../../binary/image/sheelak/0viber-image.jpg")}` alt=""/>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

To use require in your html file templates. you need to include `html-loader` for `.html files` while you have used `file-loader` for it. which might have done.

so, webpack config should be something like:

```
{
  test: /\.(html)$/,
  include: [
    path.resolve(__dirname, './frontend/pages/')
  ],
  use: [{
    loader: 'html-loader',
    options: {
      name: '[path][name].[ext]',
      attrs: [':data-src']
    }
  }]
}


{
  test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|svg|gif|webp)$/,
  include: [
    path.resolve(__dirname, './frontend/binary/image/')
  ],
  use: [{
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
      name: 'image/[name].[ext]',
    }
  }]
}
```

**and then use** `require in img tag` as below:

More about this [here](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/html-loader)

Comment: I have already tried it, in return I get this  `module.exports = "<div class=\"slider\">\r\n\t  <img src=\"${require(\`../../binary/image/background/city_white_black_5.jpg\`)}\" width=\"50\" height=\"50\" alt=\"\" />\r\n\t  \r\n</div>";`   And I do not know how to deal with it.

Comment: @Air I cloned and ran your project on my machine(mac). its working smooth withoujt any 404. can you tell me what exactly is wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to update the repository. You can try again